# Why does 'アプリストア’ mean appstore?

Tags: katakana, loanwords, abbreviations

I initially expected 'appstore' to be アップストア

I don't see why it's translated as '**apuri**-store'

Comment: appuri = loaned word from English "application"

Answer (score 23):

The word application in Japanese is 「アプリケーション」. The shortened form (akin to `app`) is 「アプリ」, rather than just 「アップ」 as one might expect coming from English.

Therefore the word for `app store` is, as you'd expect, the word for app (アプリ) + store (ストア): アプリストア

Comment: This may be related to the fact that Japanese has fewer vowels. アップ has always meant "up" rather than "app". While ['app store' as a generic noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_store) is アプリストア, [*App Store* as the name of a service by Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)) is called アップストア in Japanese, too (it's a brand name, after all).

Comment: @naruto also, Japanese loves its three-syllable abbreviations: パソコン, ファミコン, コンビニ, and so on.

Comment: @N.Virgo, it's more four-mora abbreviations, rather than three-syllable. Consider also 高等学校【こうとうがっこう】→高校【こうこう】. Or more specifically, two-part abbreviations, taking a chunk from the two constituent terms. Consider アメリカンショートヘア → アメショ, ソビエト連邦【れんぽう】→ソ連【れん】, 自己株式【じこかぶしき】→自株【じかぶ】, etc.

Comment: @naruto they have the "same" five vowels, it just so happens that both the u in "up" and the a in "app" have アas the closest equivalent.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen vowels are sounds; "they" have 5, and 5 characters to represent them, we have 20+ vowels, with 5 dedicated characters (that can represent several different vowels, with overlaps) and 2 semi-vowels. Even though Japanese vowels can all be represented pretty closely in English, they aren't all exact either. Consider the pronunciation of the name of the letter `O` (oʊ) vs the pronunciation of `お` (o)

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell it's actually called the "App Store" in English letters, where they sell アプリ.

As for the reason they prefer アプリ...

Japanese like to shorten foreign borrowed words if they are longer than 3 or 4 sounds because unlike English, there is no good way to blend nicely like in English...you have to clearly say each.

Saying most foreign-derived words out in this long form becomes very cumbersome.

Another example would be バイト　(ba-ee-to) shortened from アルバイト (ah-ru-ba-ee-toe) meaning part-time work which is derived from the German word "Arbeit" meaning work or job.

The word "application" in Japanese is

アプリケーションソフトウェア or just アプリケーション

which you would say **ah-pu-ri-ke**(long)**-shon**

The abbreviated version アプリ has been around a lot longer than the the word "app" has been used in English, probably since the first commercial software began to be sold in Japan in the 70's. Most commonly refering to desktop software or business software.

When the word "app" became popular after smartphones arrived, the Japanese already beat English to the "let's make that darn word shorter and cooler" punch... :)

They also use アプー　(ap-pu) as well, to refer to just mobile apps. However the app store has both Apple desktop and mobile software...so I guess since アプリー　is already so close to アプー　there's no use in renaming all forms of software to newer "app".

That's my best guess....

There could also be some copyright reasons that I 'm not aware of!